# Firebase - React: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

The login.js is where the "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')*" coming from I would guess

**Login.js:**

```js
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import FirebaseContext from "../context/firebase";
import * as ROUTES from "../constants/routes";

export default function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);

  const [emailAddress, setEmailAddress] = useState(" ");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(" ");

  const [error, setError] = useState(" ");
  const isInvalid = password === "" || emailAddress === "";

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress, password);
      navigate.push(ROUTES.HOMEPAGE);
    } catch (error) {
      setEmailAddress(" ");
      setPassword(" ");
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Login - Bits&Bots";
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="login__container">
      <div className="loginform">
        <p>I will be the form</p>
        {error && <p classname="error-text">{error}</p>}

        <form onSubmit={handleLogin} method="POST">
          <input
            aria-label="Enter your email addres"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Email address"
            classname="login__input"
            onChange={({ target }) => setEmailAddress(target.value)}
          />
          <input
            aria-label="Enter your password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            classname="login__input"
            onChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
          />

          <button disabled={isInvalid} type="submit" classname="login__submit">
            Log in
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="create__account">
        <p>
          Don't have an account?{``}
          <Link to="/signup" className="signup__link">
            Sign up
          </Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**so there is a "import FirebaseContext from "../context/firebase";" in this file.
What contains inside that firebase.js file is:**

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

const FirebaseContext = createContext(null);
export default FirebaseContext;
```

So I cant seem to understand why the text "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')*" appearing when typing inside the form.

**Here is a image of it:**

[image]

**If more detailed needed, here is the index.js file:**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import FirebaseContext from "./context/firebase";
import { db, analytics, FieldValue, auth } from "./lib/firebase";

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{ db, analytics, FieldValue, auth }}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**and different firebase.js file from /lib**

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/analytics";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

// // here i want to import the seed file
// import { seedDatabase } from "../seed";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "0",
  authDomain: "0",
  projectId: "0",
  storageBucket: "0",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "0",
  measurementId: "0",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const analytics = firebaseApp.analytics();
const auth = firebase.auth();

const FieldValue = db.FieldValue;

console.log(db);

// seedDatabase(db, "db");

export { db, analytics, FieldValue, auth };
```

I will apprechiate all the help i can get.

Comment: `<FirebaseContext.Provider value={{ db, analytics, FieldValue, auth }}>` The value you're providing does not include `.firebase`. Therefore, `const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);` results in `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you @NicholasTower for your comment. I tried change the file like you wrote but still did not work, or that I might have done it wrong.

Comment: Are you using firebase v8 or v9?

Comment: @ahmedtwabi "firebase": "^9.9.0", I still havent been successful solving the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you read up on the differences between firebase v8 and v9, some of the instantiation of the firebase functions there is of v8 while some v9. I haven't used firebase for that long but in v9, a simple auth instantiation would look like this:

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "0",
  authDomain: "0",
  projectId: "0",
  storageBucket: "0",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "0",
  measurementId: "0",
};

export default const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And in another file e.g. login.js

```
import Firebase from "../Firebase";
import {getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "firebase/auth"

var auth = getAuth(Firebase);

//more code over here

const mainFunc = () => {
   //more code here
   signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
}
```

I know the compat library is there to offer backward compatibility to v8 but unless your project is super huge or something, I'd recommend you use the v9 way of doing things. It's cleaner.

heres a link to the firebase docs : https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> **firebase is missing in the import, here is the index.js file:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import FirebaseContext from "./context/firebase";
import { firebase, db, analytics, FieldValue, auth } from "./lib/firebase";

ReactDOM.rende`enter code here`r(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{firebase, db, analytics, FieldValue, auth }}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```